# Pandas groupby give any non nan values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to perform a groupby on a table where given this groupby index, all values are either correct or Nan. EG:

```
    id country    name
0    1  France    None
1    1  France  Pierre
2    2    None   Marge
3    1    None  Pierre
4    3     USA     Jim
5    3    None     Jim
6    2      UK    None
7    4   Spain  Alvaro
8    2    None   Marge
9    3    None     Jim
10   4   Spain    None
11   3    None     Jim
```

I just want to get the values for each of the 4 people, which should never clash, eg:

```
   country    name
id                
1   France  Pierre
2       UK   Marge
3      USA     Jim
4    Spain  Alvaro
```

I've tried:

```
groupby().first()
groupby.nth(0,dropna='any'/'all')
```

and even

```
groupby().apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.first_valid_index()])
```

All to no avail. What am I missing?

EDIT: to help you making the example dataframe for testing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,1,3,3,2,4,2,3,4,3],'country':['France','France',None,None,'USA',None,'UK','Spain',None,None,'Spain',None],'name':[None,'Pierre','Marge','Pierre','Jim','Jim',None,'Alvaro','Marge','Jim',None,'Jim']})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pandas [groupby.first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) returns first not-null value but does not support None, try

```
df.fillna(np.nan).groupby('id').first()

    country name
id      
1   France  Pierre
2   UK      Marge
3   USA     Jim
4   Spain   Alvaro
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible specifying to `dropna` when values are `None`

```
df.groupby('id').first(dropna=True)

   country    name
id                
1   France  Pierre
2       UK   Marge
3      USA     Jim
4    Spain  Alvaro
```