# Interiorly Merge DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that, because of one variable, didn't merge all the rows properly. After dropping that variable, I'm left with a dataframe that looks like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
                        'Col1': [2, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1],
                       'Col2': [np.nan, 1, 0, np.nan,np.nan,0,np.nan, 3, 2],
                        'Col3': [1,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1, np.nan, np.nan]
                       }
                      )

   ID   Col1    Col2    Col3
0   A   2.0     NaN     1.0
1   A   NaN     1.0     1.0
2   B   NaN     0.0     NaN
3   B   1.0     NaN     1.0
4   C   1.0     NaN     NaN
5   C   NaN     0.0     NaN
6   C   NaN     NaN     1.0
```

I can combine the rows by grouping by `ID` and taking the mean of each column

```
test_df.groupby('ID').agg('mean')

   Col1     Col2    Col3
ID          
A   2.0     1.0     1.0
B   1.0     0.0     1.0
C   1.0     0.0     1.0
```

---

For a more general case, the dataset is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
                        'Col1': [2, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1],
                       'Col2': [np.nan, 1, 0, np.nan,np.nan,0,np.nan, 3, 2],
                        'Col3': [1,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1, np.nan, np.nan]
                       }
                      )
test_df

   ID   Col1    Col2    Col3
0   A   2.0     NaN     1.0
1   A   NaN     1.0     1.0
2   B   NaN     0.0     NaN
3   B   1.0     NaN     1.0
4   C   1.0     NaN     NaN
5   C   NaN     0.0     NaN
6   C   NaN     NaN     1.0
7   D   NaN     3.0     NaN
8   D   1.0     2.0     NaN
```

The expected output is then

```
   Col1     Col2    Col3
ID          
A   2.0     1.0     1.0
B   1.0     0.0     1.0
C   1.0     0.0     1.0
D   NaN     3.0     NaN
D   1.0     2.0     NaN
```

where (ID == A) is merged because the values in Col3 match, and the rows for (ID == D) are not merged.

1. Is there a way to do this without aggregating using the mean? I've tried searching "squishing", "interior merge", but I haven't found this kind of operation. Related: what is the way to do this for the general case? Using `test_df.groupby('ID').first()` would still merged ID == D
2. What is the proper terminology for this kind of operation? :)

Comment: `test_df.groupby('ID').first()`? What should happen if the 1st row was duplicated in the input?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55284750/5755604) is rather similar, other than that @mozways comment is excellent.

Comment: If that's the case, the same values should be kept.

Comment: can you provide a full input/ouptut example with duplicates?

Comment: @mozway I've added the additional example, and another row where the values don't align.